# general solution of a differential equation in explicit form

Tags: differential

I need to find the general solution of a differential equation in explicit form

$$\dfrac {dp}{dh} = -Kp$$

My solution: I used the separation of variables and after doing the integrations I obtained $\ln p = -Kh + c$

The general solution in explicit form, by an index law I obtained
$$p = e^c e^{-Kh}$$
$$p = Ae^{-Kh}$$

Is my working correct, please?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

No, the derivation is not quite correct. What if $p=0$ or $p<0$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution is correct.